# Content is being add horizontally to JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

im starting to work with java Swing and i was trying to make a system to show something like a Map :

[image]

But when i try to add another **entry** to the JSCrollPane it's being **added horizontally** intead of vertically, i have tried everything i don't what i mithgt be doing wrong but i can't manage do fix it.

Here i create the Frame :

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    final JPanel content = new JPanel();
    new DataEntry("", 0).create(content);

    final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(content, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    scrollPane.setWheelScrollingEnabled(true);
    panel.add(scrollPane);

    scrollPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 60));

    final JButton add = new JButton("Add");
    add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new DataEntry("", 0).create(content);
        }
    });

    panel.add(add);

    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.pack();

    frame.setVisible(true);
```

And this is how i create the Entry :

```
    public JPanel create(final JPanel content) {
    final JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    final JPanel fields = new JPanel();

    fields.add(new JLabel("Variable"));
    fields.add(variable);
    fields.add(new JLabel("Row"));
    fields.add(row);

    panel.add(fields);

    JButton remove = new JButton("Remove");
    remove.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            content.remove(panel);
            content.revalidate();
        }
    });

    panel.add(remove);

    content.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    content.revalidate();

    return panel;
}
```

At the start i was wondering why it wasn't displaying any new Entry, then i tried changing HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER > HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED and then i realized that the variables were being add horizontally.

Here is a gif to see what's going on (Couldn't manage to take a proper photo) : [GIF](https://gyazo.com/3242d2622416c6076edca33911f42f83)

Comment: the default layout for a JPanel is a FlowLayout, which just lays out items in a horizontal line. If you want them laid out vertically, use a BoxLayout

Comment: So it was so simply... It has been driving my crazy and now its fixed so simply, well at least its fixed. But after i tried it i have seen two things : It does only display 1 Entry at time, and the Scroll is really slow, ¿ how i can fix this ?

Comment: `It does only display 1 Entry at time` - the "CENTER" of a BorderLayout can only display a single component. You need to add each Entry to the panel using the BoxLayout, not the content pane.

Comment: I haven't been able to do this, i mean i have set the BorderLayout to the JPanel but i can't manage to make the JScrollPanel bigger.